# git push hangs and fails after POST git-receive-pack

Tags: git, gitignore, git-lfs

I am trying to push my repository that has a lot of `.png`, `.mp4`, `.h5` files, that I can ignore.

#### the directory structure:

```py
.gitignore
CV PROJECT
├───.vscode
├───Docker
├───src
│   ├───Game
│   ├───Main
│   │   └───__pycache__  
│   └───Video
│       ├───Images       
│       │   ├───test    
│       │   │   ├───boost # dir that has .png files 
│       │   │   ├───click # dir that has .png files 
│       │   │   └───upgrade # dir that has .png files 
│       │   └───train  
│       │       ├───boost # dir that has .png files 
│       │       ├───click # dir that, has .png files 
│       │       └───upgrade # dir that has .png files 
│       ├───Models # dir that has .h5 files  
│       └───Videos
│           ├───boost # dir that has .mp4 files
│           ├───click # dir that has .mp4 files
│           └───upgrade # dir that has .mp4 files
└───Tutorial
    └───.ipynb_checkpoints
```

***tl;dr*** what does my `.gitignore` need to look like?

---

### the commands:

```py
git config --global http.postBuffer 2048M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 1024M
git config --global core.compression 9

git config --global ssh.postBuffer 2048M
git config --global ssh.maxRequestBuffer 1024M

git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m 
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 256m

# git hangs here
git push --verbose -f origin master
```

#### the output:

git hangs here:

```
Total 133 (delta 29), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
POST git-receive-pack (569667108 bytes)
```

so i tried to ignore them using this `.gitignore`:

```
*.mp4
*.h5


Models/*
Videos/*
test/*
train/*

boost/*
upgrade/*
click/*
```

and got this output:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), completed with 1 local object.
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/boost/b7.mp4 is 57.86 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/click/c7.mp4 is 73.08 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/upgrade/u6.mp4 is 56.50 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 3a803801864c0608c9e57dd7cf9d3ee3eaca6a180713b3c7119e8b0414c776ee
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File src/Video/medmodel.h5 is 112.78 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/romhayh/special-mario.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/romhayh/special-mario.git'
```

after this i converted the `.gitignore` to `.gitattributes` (to not use `git lfs track`) and got the same error message:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), completed with 1 local object.
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/boost/b7.mp4 is 57.86 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/click/c7.mp4 is 73.08 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File src/Video/Videos/upgrade/u6.mp4 is 56.50 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 9add1b6eba287591037b40a5a483a1b7bb9d2746853150a2146bdf83b8e58b9c
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File src/Video/Models/medmodel.h5 is 112.78 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File src/Video/medmodel.h5 is 112.78 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *good* real-world analogy is tricky here, but suppose you have a cement delivery service.  You delivered, to some customer, 1000 cubic yards of cement, which have now set.  Your customer calls you up and says they did not want that much cement: they only wanted *ten* cubic yards.  So you have your trucks deliver them another 10 yards of cement.  Did you improve their situation, or just make it worse?

Now, the reason for the above analogy is simple enough: Git commits only ever *add new stuff* to the repository.  If you put a giant file into some commit, that giant file is in that commit *forever*.  If someone didn't want that giant file, and you make a *new* commit that *lacks* the giant file, well, now you have *two* commits: one with the giant file, and one without.  The second commit *depends on, and therefore requires, the first commit*.

No matter what else you do, if you keep adding on new commits, you're just making everything worse.  What you need is not more cement (er, commits).  You need some kind of jackhammer and cement-removal service (something to *remove* commits from your repository).

That's not all, though!  While we already see that listing a file in `.gitignore` has no effect on any existing commit—no *existing* commit can ever be changed, at all; you just have to get them hauled away and stop using them entirely to get rid of them—it also has no good effect on *new* commits, at least *not yet*.  If a file is *tracked*, it has no effect on that file in *future* commits either.

So:

- Your first job is to remove some commit(s).  We generally do this with `git reset`.  The `git reset` command is destructive!  Be very careful here: you probably should work on a *clone* of your repository, rather than the original.
- Then, having removed the bad commit(s), you may need to *explicitly remove* the large files, so that they are no longer *tracked*.  A file is *tracked*, in Git, if the file is in Git's index.  How do you know if a file is in Git's index?  Well, you know because it's tracked.  This is kind of a circular problem, as you can see. :-)  But if you definitely want it *not*-tracked, you can run:

  ```
  git rm --cached src/Video/Videos/boost/b7.mp4
  ```

  for instance (for the file named `src/Video/Videos/boost/b7.mp4`).  This will remove the file from Git's index, if it is present *in* Git's index (is tracked), or will give you an error about the file not being in Git if the file *isn't* present in Git's index (is untracked).  So either way, you can now be sure that the file is *untracked*.

When a file *is* untracked, `git status` usually whines about it.  The `.gitignore` listing makes `git status` shut up about it.  That's often the main feature of `.gitignore`: making `git status` behave.  The other feature is that, as long as some file currently *is* untracked, listing that file in `.gitignore` means that `git add --all` or `git add *` won't *add* it to Git's index, which would make it tracked.

The tracked-ness of some file is not exactly something you set once and forget.  Because *commits* are unchangeable, once you've made some commit and that commit *does* have the file in it, any time you use `git checkout` to *extract* that commit, the file goes into Git's index and is thus once again tracked.  You can use `git rm --cached` to un-track the file, so that it does not go into *new* commits you make.  But you cannot remove it from existing commits, ever: no *existing* commit can *ever change*.

#### What you must do is remove the *bad* commits and then *not commit the files again*

You *can* put the files into Git-LFS, if you want to do that.  (Git-LFS has its own weirdness and quirks.  I only bring this up because you did, with the [git-lfs](/questions/tagged/git-lfs) tag and with a mention of LFS in your question.)  But you have to get rid of the existing commits that have the big files in them.  Only you can say which commits those are, because those commits are in *your* repository, which nobody else has.

This is why I recommend that you clone your existing repository first, before trying to remove any of the bad commits.  You may, however, find some other tools and/or methods more useful here.  See, e.g., [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/1256452)